# Find a normal matrix with a given characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find a normal matrix with characteristic polynomial $t^2 + 4$ and eigenspace
$E_{2i} = span  {(1 \ 3i)^t}$

Since any vector in different eignespaces are perpendicular to each other, so i compute $E_{-2i} = span  {(-3 \ i)^t}$. Then I conclude that the matrix is \begin{matrix}
        1 & 3i  \\
        -3 & i\\
        \end{matrix}

Then when I try to calculate back the char. polynomial, I didn't get back the same ans.

What's wrong with my ans?

Thank you!

Comment: You have to calculate $Ae_1$ and $Ae_2$. Let $u$ and $v$ be the two normalized(!) eigenvectors. Then $e_1 = \langle e_1,u\rangle u+\langle e_1,v\rangle v$ and so $Ae_1 = \langle e_1,u\rangle Au + \langle e_1,v\rangle Av = 2i\langle e_1,u\rangle u -2i\langle e_1,v\rangle v$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just put the eigenvectors into a matrix (in rows). However, your matrix $A$ is really defined by $A=PDP^{-1}$, with

$$D=\left(\begin{matrix}2i & 0 \\ 0 &-2i\end{matrix}\right)$$

And

$$P=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & -3 \\ 3i & i\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then you find

$$A=-\frac{2}{5}\left(\begin{matrix}4i & -3 \\ 3 & -4i\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then $AA^*=A^*A=\left(\begin{matrix}4 & 0 \\ 0 &4\end{matrix}\right)$ so $A$ is normal, and by construction it has the stated eigenvalues.

---

The [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) tells us a normal matrix is diagonalizable by a unitary matrix, hence you can normalize the colums of $P$ to make it unitary:

$$P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\left(\begin{matrix}1 & -3 \\ 3i & i\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then $PP^*=I$.

Note also that your statement that eigenspaces are orthogonal to each other is wrong in general. Here it's true because $A$ is supposed to be normal.

The converse is easy to check: when $A$ is diagonalizable by a unitary matrix, that is $A=PDP^*$, then you get $AA^*=(PDP^*)(PD^*P^*)=PDD^*P^*=PD^*DP^*=(PD^*P^*)(PDP^*)=A^*A$.

Comment: @mathshungry If you normalize the columns of $P$ then $P^{-1}$ is just $P^*$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Oh, I think I see now what you had in mind: by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem), $A$ is diagonalizable by a unitary matrix, since it's normal. So yes, it's probably better to normalize, though it does not change the result.